# MacBook Air 2013 with circle slash while trying to install Mojave

Tags: mojave

I've always been a Linux and Windows user, but I bought this used MacBook Air to mess with. I figured a fresh install was best for it so I erased the primary drive in disk utility and got a known-working Mojave installer from work to reinstall Mojave. However, I get about 2/3rds of the way to the loading screen before it goes to circle-slash. I reset SMC, PRAM 3-4 times, and also reformatted the SSD to no avail; always hangs on the same step. Anyone know what might be the issue?

Comment: Not an answer to your question about *why* it doesn't work but you could try internet recovery and then upgrade to Mojave.

Comment: That means it has been used on multiple other Macs to install Mojave. @lx07, that worked to get Mountain Lion 10.8.5 on there, but when I try to install High Sierra or El Capitan on the App Store, I get a warning that my OS is too old to use the App Store. When trying Mojave, it tells me it won't run on my machine... I'm confused. Isn't Apple supposed to be easier than this?

Answer (score 1):

Updater didn't find a previous OS X install.

> Technical requirements:
>
> - OS X 10.8 or later
> - 2 GB of memory
> - 15 GB of available storage to perform upgrade
> - Some features require an Apple ID
> - Some features require internet access
>
> Mac Hardware requirements:
>
> - MacBook: Early-2015 or newer
> - MacBook Pro: Mid-2012 or newer
> - MacBook Air: Mid-2012 or newer
> - Mac Mini: Late-2012 or newer
> - iMac: Late-2012 or newer
> - iMac Pro: Late-2017 or newer
> - Mac Pro: Late-2013 or newer, mid-2010 and mid-2012 models with recommended Metal-capable GPU

What caught my attention was the
requirement for OS X 10.8 or later. Which (to me) indicates that a *previous* Mac OS X version *needs* to *already* be installed.
So if I were you, I'd probably get my hands on a copy of Mountain Lion, and install that first. Then attempt to install Mojave from there.

While you indicate yours is 2013, if it does turn out to be matter of your hardware being too old. Do note, that the OS Installer has a white, or blacklist that it consults to determine whether the hardware is an actual candidate for install/upgrade. I used to know where this file (`.kext`) was
located. But have since forgotten. A search on the internet should quickly reveal the location of the `.kext` file. Good sources for this information are in Hackintosh venues. :)

In case you didn't already know, and are interested. You can easily make a (USB stick) installer in the following fashion:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Mojave.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume
```

where `/Volumes/MyVolume` should point to your USB stick (formatted with a GUID Partition Map and Mac OS Extended (Journaled) )

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks mate. I know for a fact though that I have used this exact method that I'm using now on Macs that I have wiped clean to reinstall the OS with no issue at all. Some of those Macs even dated back to 2013, but primarily were on newer ones. The system before had Mojave installed but it had an admin password on it, hence why I had to reinstall Mojave.